# MonetDB Insert Statement Returning id support in Golang

Tags: go, monetdb

I am trying to run this insert query statement using golang which should return an id

```
INSERT INTO users (u_email,u_phone,u_password_hash) VALUES (?,?,?) RETURNING u_user_id;
```

it seems there is no support for that in MonetDB.

Well i tried to get the id by unique email when the insert is done without the "RETURNING u_user_id" part as below

```
func GetByEmail(db *sql.DB) {
    userid := `SELECT u_user_id FROM users WHERE u_email = ?;`

    var id UserResponse
    email := `baicmr@email.com`

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(userid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()
    result := stmt.QueryRow(email)
    if getErr := result.Scan(&id.ID); getErr != nil {
        log.Panic(getErr)
    }
    fmt.Printf("id.ID: %v\n", id.ID)
}
```

the result.Scan() line panics

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

What am i doing which is wrong

Comment: Are you using a specific driver? If so, does it have a `LastInsertId` or equivalent?

Comment: if i use ```LastInsertedId``` i get a -1 int64 while my id column is a UUID type

Comment: Try using Golang's [sqlx](https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) package. It provides lot of support for features which are not in the sql package.

Comment: Something for you to refer. [https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/github.com.jmoiron.sqlx/DB/NamedQuery/golang-db-namedquery-method-examples.html](https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/github.com.jmoiron.sqlx/DB/NamedQuery/golang-db-namedquery-method-examples.html)

Comment: MonetDB insert statement does not allow returning id, correct me if i am wrong because i have tried both sql and sqlx. The NameQuery in sqlx return a row which you can .Next() for the returned id but since MonetDB as i have tried so far it does not allow returning id hence NamedQuery panics at the row.Next() just like QueryRow() panics at row.Scan()

Answer (score 0):

Can you please open a issue/feature request over at: https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go ? This looks like a bug.

Comment: here is the code in go playground `https://go.dev/play/p/bApu0avz1nz`

Comment: here is the code in go playground [link](https://go.dev/play/p/bApu0avz1nz)